# How to fetch all videos and photos from specific folder in android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android application in which I am fetching Videos and Photos from Whatsapp Status Folder and when user clicks on it he can save these videos,photos. These are saving in WhatsappProDir Folder. Now I want to fetch media from this folder(WhatsappProDir). How can I do this? How can I fetch media from folder which is programmatically created?

Code for fetching videos and download them:

```
private void getStatusVideo() {
    if(MyConstants.STATUS_DIRECTORY.exists()){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File[] statusfile = MyConstants.STATUS_DIRECTORY.listFiles();
                if(statusfile!= null && statusfile.length>0){
                    Arrays.sort(statusfile);
                    for(final File statusfil: statusfile){
                        StatusModel statusModel = new StatusModel(statusfil, statusfil.getName(), statusfil.getAbsolutePath());
                        statusModel.setThumbnail(getThumbnail(statusModel));
                        if(statusModel.isVideo()) {
                            statusModels.add(statusModel);
                        }

                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(statusModels, getContext(), WhatsappVideoFragment.this);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
                            videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });

                }else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dir does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
private Bitmap getThumbnail(StatusModel statusModel) {
    if(statusModel.isVideo()){
        return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(statusModel.getFile().getAbsolutePath(),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    }else {
         return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(statusModel.getFile().getAbsolutePath()),
                MyConstants.THUMBSIZE, MyConstants.THUMBSIZE);

    }
}
public void downloadImage(StatusModel statusModel) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(MyConstants.APP_DIR);
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    File destFile = new File(file+File.separator + statusModel.getTitle());
    if(destFile.exists()){
        destFile.delete();
    }
    if(copyFile(statusModel.getFile(), destFile)){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        i.setData(Uri.fromFile(destFile));
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error in Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private boolean copyFile(File file, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.getParentFile().exists()){
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    if(!destFile.exists()){
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    destination.transferFrom(source,0, source.size());
    source.close();;
    destination.close();
    return true;
}
```

I can't understand how to do this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? let's say the listFiles method of the File class, with some filters could help you out

Comment: you can see my edited code. This is the code which i tried for fetching videos from Whatsapp Status folder and download them.Everything is working fine. But now i want to fetch these downloaded videos. How to do this?

Comment: Is that Whatsapp Status folder on the internet? Or where? Please give full path of WhatsappProDir Folder.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator+"WhatsAppStatusProDir";

Comment: this is the full path of WhatsappProDir